# iPhone UIView resources

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been looking for little more deeply **UIView** introduction resources, such as e-book, video or tutorials. Positioning, subclassing, frame, bouds, subviews, creating programmatically, loading from xib, both, etc.

I didn't find good resource about it, I would like to hear suggestions ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple documentation for views](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) is actually very good for this. [The Big Nerd Ranch iPhone book](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide) has given me many Aha! moments, especially about view controllers. [Erica Sadun's iPhone Developers Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659570) has always been good for nitty gritty information.

Those are a few I've found, but like you I'd love to have just one really great book or tutorial to fill in the many gaps in my `UIView` knowledge.